# Can modules referring to parent pom by relative path be depended on by 3rd parties?

Tags: maven

I have a parent module, which defines its version as follows:

```
    <groupId>org.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-id</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>${library.version}</version>

    <properties>
        <library.version>1.0.0</library.version>
    </properties>
```

Then I have a sub module, which points to its parent as follows:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-id</artifactId>
        <version>${library.version}</version>
        <relativePath>../../</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>child-id</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

And I depend on it in my other projects like so:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>child-id</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This results in the following error for me:

> Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.group:child-id:1.0.0: Failure to find org.group:parent-id:pom:${library.version}

Can this problem be solved without resorting to `mvn versions:set` in my multi module project to manage explicit versions in all poms?

/edit: currently solved this problem with [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54600133/441662) that makes using `mvn versions:set` a little easier.

Comment: Does the 1.0.0 version of the parent installed in the local m2? (or in your repository manager) And if it is, version 1.0.0 of the parent has the parent.property.library.version property.

Comment: @SilverShroud Yes it is there in my local .m2 and the property is there as well. I've updated the question to include the relevant parent pom part.

Comment: If you need to define a relative path for a parent different than the default which means giving nothing in the parent definition this is an indication that you should change your folder structure according those relationships....

Comment: Are you use maven 3.5 or above, there were some problems in prior maven versions for this kind of usages

Comment: maven 3.5 currently

Comment: @SilverShroud What kind of problems are you talking about?

Comment: @khmarbaise I did not try previous versions, but from the following link I thought previous versions are not suitable for these kind of usages. https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html#Multi_Module_Setup

Comment: @SilverShroud If you reference to ci friendly all your given examples in your post will not work cause ci friendly supports only the following three values `revision`, `changelist` and `sha1`....